# Product Inventory program that takes products with an ID, quantity, and price and uses an Inventory class to keep track of the products

Tags: python, oop

The Product class seems to work fine but I'm trying to figure out how to get the Inventory class to separate each product into there specific categories. I feel like I'm close but whenever I try and print out the inventory it just shows where it's stored in memory and doesn't actually print anything out. The output i receive when running is at the bottom. I want it to print out the actual products and data, not the instance of it stored in memory.

```
class Product:

    def __init__(self, pid, price, quantity):
        self.pid = pid 
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    def __str__(self):
        #Return the strinf representing the product
        return "Product ID: {}\t Price: {}\t Quantity: {}\n".format(self.pid, self.price, self.quantity)

    def get_id(self):
        #returns id 
        return self.pid

    def get_price(self):
        #returns price
        return self.price

    def get_quantity(self):
        #returns quantity
        return self.quantity

    def increase_quantity(self):
        self.quantity += 1

    def decrease_quantity(self):
        self.quantity -= 1 


    def get_value(self):
        value = self.quantity * self.price
        return 'value is {}'.format(value)


product_1 = Product('fishing', 20, 10)
product_2 = Product('apparel', 35, 20)


class Inventory:

    def __init__(self, products):
        self.products = products
        self.fishing_list = []
        self.apparel_list = []
        self.value = 0 


    def __repr__(self):
    return "Inventory(products: {}, fishing_list: {}, apparel_list: {}, value: {})".format(self.products, self.fishing_list, self.apparel_list, self.value)

    def add_fishing(self):
        for product in self.products:
            if product.get_id() == 'fishing':
                self.fishing_list.append(product)
        return '{} is in the fishing section'.format(self.fishing_list)

    def add_apparel(self):
        for product in self.products:
            if product.get_id() == 'apparel':
                self.apparel_list.append(product)
        return '{} is in the apparel section'.format(self.apparel_list)


inventory_1 = Inventory([product_1, product_2])
inventory_1.add_fishing()
print(inventory_1)
```

OUTPUT = Inventory(products: [<**main**.Product instance at 0x10dbc8248>, <**main**.Product instance at 0x10dbc8290>], fishing_list: [<**main**.Product instance at 0x10dbc8248>], apparel_list: [], value: 0)

Comment: *"doesn't actually print anything out."*: Thats correct, you didn't implement **how** to print, therefore you got the default output. Read about [object.__str__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify how an object of the class `Inventory` should be printed.

To do this you need to implement at least one of the following functions in your class.

- `__repr__`
- `__str__`

This answer helps, which of both you should use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/8411228

An implementation could look something like this:

```
class Inventory:
    # your code ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.products) + str(self.fishing_list) + str(self.apparel_list) + str(self.value)

    # or even better with formatting
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Inventory(products: {self.products}, fishing_list: {self.fishing_list}, apparel_list: {self.apparel_list}, value: {self.value})
```

Note that I used in the second example [f strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#rationale), to format the output string.